# Drawing Routes on a Map

Tags: java, android, graphics, controller

I have this class:

```
public class MapController
{
    private Polyline _currentPolyline; // The line connecting two locations on the map
    private GoogleMap _map;
    private Context _context;

    public MapController(GoogleMap map, Context context)
    {
        _map = map;
        _context = context;
    }

    /**
     * Draws a route on the map.
     *
     * @param directions the Google Map Directions JSON string with the routes
     * @throws JSONException
     */
    public void drawRoute(String directions) throws JSONException
    {
        // First parse the JSON to extract the points into an easily manipulated form
        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new DirectionsHelper().parsePathsFromJson(directions);

        // Only one polyline can be shown on the map at a time
        hideRoute();

        ArrayList<LatLng> points;
        PolylineOptions polyLineOptions = null;

        // Traversing through routes
        for (int i = 0; i < routes.size(); i++)
        {
            points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            polyLineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = routes.get(i);

            for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++)
            {
                HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                points.add(position);
            }

            polyLineOptions.addAll(points);
            polyLineOptions.color(ContextCompat.getColor(_context, R.color.colorPrimary));
        }

        _currentPolyline =  _map.addPolyline(polyLineOptions);
    }

    /**
     * Removes the currently drawn {@link Polyline} from the map.
     */
    public void hideRoute()
    {
        if (_currentPolyline != null)
        {
            _currentPolyline.removeRoute();
        }
    }
}
```

Is it generally a good practice to call `hideRoute()` inside the `drawRoute()` method or does it depend on other factors? For example: should the caller be responsible for clearing the map before drawing the new path or does the caller not care?

Comment: When you say `clearRoute()` do you mean `hideRoute()`? I don't see `clearRoute()` in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From an algorithm flow viewpoint, it looks good. However, I'd make a few small changes:

```
public void drawRoute(String directions) throws JSONException
{
    // First parse the JSON to extract the points into an easily manipulated form
    List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new DirectionsHelper().parsePathsFromJson(directions);

    // Only one polyline can be shown on the map at a time
    hideRoute();

    ArrayList<LatLng> points;
    PolylineOptions polyLineOptions = null;

    // Traversing through routes
    for (int i = 0; i < routes.size(); i++)
    {
        points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        polyLineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
        List<HashMap<String, String>> path = routes.get(i);

        for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++)
        {
            HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

            double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
            LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

            points.add(position);
        }

        polyLineOptions.addAll(points);
        polyLineOptions.color(ContextCompat.getColor(_context, R.color.colorPrimary));
    }

    _currentPolyline =  _map.addPolyline(polyLineOptions);
}
```

In drawRoute, you first declare `polyLineOptions = new PolylineOptions();`, and then after the for loop, you assign values.

I think it'd be better if you moved the creation of `PolylineOptions` so that it's created and used in one place:

```
 public void drawRoute(String directions) throws JSONException
{
    // First parse the JSON to extract the points into an easily manipulated form
    List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new DirectionsHelper().parsePathsFromJson(directions);

    // Only one polyline can be shown on the map at a time
    hideRoute();

    ArrayList<LatLng> points;
    PolylineOptions polyLineOptions = null;

    // Traversing through routes
    for (int i = 0; i < routes.size(); i++)
    {
        points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        List<HashMap<String, String>> path = routes.get(i);

        for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++)
        {
            HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

            double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
            LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

            points.add(position);
        }

        polyLineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
        polyLineOptions.addAll(points);
        polyLineOptions.color(ContextCompat.getColor(_context, R.color.colorPrimary));
    }

    _currentPolyline =  _map.addPolyline(polyLineOptions);
}
```

And for the `hideRoute` function,

```
public void hideRoute()
{
    if (_currentPolyline != null)
    {
        _currentPolyline.removeRoute();
    }
}
```

You should set `_currentPolyline` to `null` so you can't remove it twice (if that matters), plus it allows the GC to clean up the polyline.

Comment: So, you have basically answered that it's ok to clear the `Polyline` before drawing the routes inside the drawing method. Plus, a small improvement about instantiation of `PolylineOptions`.  I don't need to GC the `Polyline`, because the `MapController` instance is associated with another `Singleton` class and destroyed when the application exits. So, overall it looks superb! Thank you!